# Cannot resolve method setText - AndroidStudio

Tags: android, settext

Sorry in advance, this is the first project I've done with android.

I am trying to make text in the php file appear, but `setText` is saying it can't resolve the method. I'm sure there are many things I've done wrong here, but the `setText` is the only error at the moment.

```
private String itemTitle;
private String itemDate;
private String itemContent;

Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener = new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

        NewsRecord record = new NewsRecord();
        try {
            record.title = response.getString("title");
            record.shortInfo = response.getString("short_info");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        itemTitle.setText(record.title);
        itemDate.setText(record.date);
        itemContent.setText(record.shortInfo);

    }
    };

        Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        };


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int recordId = intent.getIntExtra("record_id", 0);

        String url = "http://www.tnt.com/projects/newsfeed/getList.php";

        new JsonObjectRequest(url, null, listener, errorListener);


    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String`s do not have a `setText()` method. You are probably looking for something that extends `TextView`.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, thanks a lot for the help. Do you know a way to do this using `setText` , Or is `TextView` the only way?

Comment: I do not know what you want to do. Do you just want to initialize those Strings?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I'm trying to pull the text from the php file in my code, so it shows up, if that makes sense?

Comment: So you are try to communicate with a server, parse some JSON and show it on the screen?

Comment: Yes, I have a `listView`, in another class and it displays the text titles from the php file, but now I want to make it so, when you click on one of the titles in the `listView` it displays the content (title, date, short_info) from the file.