# Change button's text programmatically in android studio problem

Tags: android, button, text

Why is this code wrong? It doesn't accept the setText function on a button.

```
findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("button" + Integer.toString(i), "id", getPackageName()))
                .setText("abc");
```

But if I write like this

```
button1.setText("abc");
```

it is ok.

Comment: `You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `findViewById` returns a view. View does not have a method called `setText()`. You should define that the view is a `Button` which does have a method called `setText()`.
You can do that this way.

`((Button)findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("button" + Integer.toString(i), "id", getPackageName()))).setText("abc");`

Comment: It works, thank you. But I have a question: why I received a down vote?

Comment: I do not know but I assume that similar questions have been already asked. For example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27538674/cannot-resolve-method-settext-androidstudio) kind of answers your question. If this answers your question, you can accept it.